Does anyone have a default PostgreSQL pg_hba.conf and pg_ident.conf File for postgres version 15?
I've messed my pg_hba.conf file up, and I kinda reinstalled 3 times and i opened the pg_hba.conf for version 15 there was nothing inside. so yeah.
if someone has pg_ident.conf file for postgres version 15 it will be great. thanks
also i ran into another problem:
postgres=# CREATE DATABASE thingsboard;
CREATE DATABASE
postgres=# \q
postgres@cst-server:~$ sudo nano /etc/thingsboard/conf/thingsboard.conf
[sudo] password for postgres: 
Sorry, try again.
[sudo] password for postgres: 
Sorry, try again.
[sudo] password for postgres: 
sudo: 3 incorrect password attempts

